# Benefit of factory class over other polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, factory

I'm trying to figure out the purpose of factory classes in Java. Everywhere I look it says the purpose is

1. to create objects without exposing the creation logic to the client
2. to refer to newly created object using a common interface

Examples show an interface, e.g.

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw();
}
```

with some concrete classes implementing this interface e.g.

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
   @Override
   public void draw() {
      // Draw circle
   }
}
```

and a factory, e.g.

```
public class ShapeFactory {
   public Shape getShape(String shapeType){
      if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("CIRCLE")){
         return new Circle();
      }
      // implement other types of shape
      return null;
   }
}
```

Use of the factory is something along the lines of:

```
Shape shape1 = shapeFactory.getShape("CIRCLE");
```

**My question is: how is this any better than just using pure polymorphism without a factory**, e.g.:

```
Shape shape1 = new Circle();
```

It seems to me that this achieves the common interface just like a factory. I'm not quite sure what the benefit of 'hiding the creation logic' is, when it seems like the creation logic of creating a circle is exactly the same as the creation logic of creating a factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit of using factories is that they offer a form of abstraction even greater than typical inheritance can offer. For example:

**What does the factory do to produce the object?**

Does it allocate a new object? Does it access a pool, to conserve resources? Using a factory, it's possible that the 'new' keyword is never used, saving memory and/or GC overhead. The factory can perform actions which a constructor normally shouldn't do, such as making remote proceedure calls, or accessing a database. Sometimes, the factory will return a Future instance, meaning that it could be doing the actual processing in a parallel thread!

**Where does the factory come from?**

Did you implement the factory yourself? Import the factory from a library? Was it injected through some form of IoC? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Is summary, factories are used because they are pretty much the ultimate form of abstraction for producing something

Comment: Why shouldn't these types of actions be performed in a regular constructor?

Comment: It's considered poor programming practice to have a constructor take that much time. A constructor should be basically instantaneous, because you have no choice but to block the calling thread until it completes

Comment: Also, as is the case for inversion of control, some of these things are simply impossible for a constructor to do. For example, it's impossible to checkout an instance of A from a pool if you call 'new A'. 'new' litteraly means 'allocate a new instance of this', and cannot mean 'grab an unused, existing instance from the pool'. Inversion of control is impossible for constructors to use by their nature, because inversion control means that the mechanism for creating the object is determined elsewhere in the code, or in configuration

Comment: Wouldn't you have the same problem with a factory? Or do people not care if a factory takes a long time?

Comment: 1) A factory can return a Future instance, which means it can work on the result, while the calling thread continues to do something else in the mean time. 2) A factory can utilize additional, parallel threads for processor-intensive activities. 3) It can be documented that the factory takes time, and users would accept this, where this would be unusual for a constructor. 4) Remember the other, non-time related reasons (IoC has become a huge deal)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that was a really bad example they gave you. The factory pattern has less to do with polymorphism, and more to do with minimizing the use of the "`new`" keyword.

Lets say I build a class called `Manager`. When I build it, it takes in a `String` and an `int`, because all it is managing is a `Person` object, with a name and age.

But when I grow my application, I eventually want to operate on new types of data, like adding an occupation field to my person. I want my manager to be able to take in an `Enum` for Occupation in its constructor along with the `String` and `int`.

Then a year later, my application has grown so much, I have subclasses of people, Data Access Objects, and all sorts of data I need to pass in to my manager.  If I was not using factory, then ANYWHERE in the code where I instantiated a `Manager` class, I have to fix the constructor.

If instead I have used a `ManagerFactory` class, with a method `getManager()` I only need to change the constructor inside my factory class, allowing all references to `getManager()` to still return a `Manager`, no change required.

Comment: Couldn't you just edit the constructors of the Manager class to handle these new pieces of information? E.g. add a new constructor that accepts both the old arguments AND the new arguments.

Comment: You could, but why would you want to? this is far easier, easily scalable, and is organized enough for someone new to your code to read clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Factory design pattern is about creating families of objects, not a signle object. Eg GUI app can use different concrete factories to draw elements in different styles.

Answer (score 0):

> when it seems like the creation logic of creating a circle is exactly the same as the creation logic of creating a factory.

You've captured a big part of your confusion right there.  In cases where creation starts getting more involved (see [KeyFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/security/KeyFactory.java)), it can simplify both your code, and the code of your consumers.

Answer (score 0):

A Factory pattern is one that returns an instance of one of several possible classes depending on the data provided to it.Its a "design pattern". You can implement it even by using "polymorphism". This pattern provide a wrapper around the object creation process of "similar object".

A factory Pattern can be used to -

1. Reduce the complexity of the client code by hiding object creation process
2. Provide a common interface to expose newly created object.
3. When a class can’t anticipate which class of object it needs to create.

For details, you can refer http://dgmjava.blogspot.in/2011/11/factory-design-pattern.html